# Отследить время нахождения на сайте и передать в Яндекс.Метрику

Tags: javascript

Извините, я в js совсем не силён, а директолог одного из заказчика попросил написать скрипт для отслеживания времени нахождения посетителя на сайте.

Убедительно прошу помочь)

Задача:

1. Отследить время нахождения посетителя на сайте с момента загрузки страницы.
2. Если пользователь провел на сайте с момента загрузки страницы < 11 секунд, ничего не делать.
3. Если пользователь провел на сайте с момента загрузки страницы >=11 секунд, передать событие ping в Яндекс.Метрику.

Пробовал сам, скриптов в интернете вроде как немало, но я не пойму как "идентифицировать" посетителя, если он не авторизованный. И даже если задать посетителю случайный идентификатор, как потом с этим будет работать директолог? Ведь задача, как я понимаю, потом демонстрировать этим посетителям рекламу...

Comment: " Ведь задача, как я понимаю, потом демонстрировать этим посетителям рекламу...". Судя по Задаче надо просто собрать статистику. Рекламу показывать это другая история.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин в этом то и суть, что задача - показать рекламу, но это - не моя задача. У Директа, условно, есть же какая-то система идентификации посетителей сайта, чтобы в дальнейшем настраивать ретаргетинг и прочие моменты.
Получается, даже собрав статистику я никак не помогу решить задачу, стоящую перед директологом.
Верно?

Comment: Ну так это задача яндекса. Его метрика и директ сами рзберутся кто есть кто. Вы отправите событие в метрику и на этом ваша задача решена. Почитайте их доку или с директологом поговорите, узнайте как это работает.

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы будете создавать событие достижения цели (пользователь был на сайте больше 11 секунд) в метрике. На основе этой цели в директе будет ретаргетинг (https://yandex.ru/support/direct/impression-criteria/retargeting-lists.html#retargeting-lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:
Время посещения вы можете сохранить время в localstorage, примерно вот так:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('time_visit') == null) {
    localStorage.setItem('time_visit', Date.now()) //текущее время сохранится в localstorage
}
```

С помощью SetTimeout вы можете отсчитать 11 секунд с момента открытия сайта, после чего отправить данные в яндекс:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    // Здесь ваш код передающий данные на яндекс метрику, либо в локальное хранилище
}, 11000);
```

Что касается общего времени проведения на сайте, то могу порекомендовать отслеживать каждый запрос на сервер и обновлять значение в localstorage с помощью метода описанного выше

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы идентифицировать посетителя, ему надо присвоить идентификатор и где-то его сохранить. Например можно создать запись в [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Если у пользователя нет записи в sessionStorage, то можно записать туда текущее время. Запустить таймер ([setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)) на 11 секунд, по таймеру отправить запрос в метрику. Если пользователь перезагрузит страницу (перейдёт на другую по ссылке на сайте), то таймер очевидно сбросится. Тогда надо взять текущее время и сравнить его с записью в sessionStorage, если больше 11 секунд, то пингануть метрику.

```
@startuml

title Время нахождения на сайте


start

if (есть запись о времени захода на сайт в sessionStorae?) then (нет)
  :Создать запись;
endif

:Вычислить время прбывания;

if (время пребывания > N?) then (да)
  :Отправить пинг немедленно;
else (нет)
  :Отправить пинг через N - время пребывания;
endif

stop

@enduml
```

https://www.planttext.com